# Why does 'late' use here but not 'early'?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

Why do 'late' use here but not 'early'?

> It may be that the next generation on the Divide will be very happy,
>   but the present one came too **late** in life.

On the Divide
by Willa Cather

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is saying that the immigrants she is discussing were too old when they arrived to adapt easily to the hard life on the continental divide.  "Too late in life" = "too old". Maybe the next generation, being born there and living there all their lives, will be happier.